# Can't unzip file using AppleScript

Tags: terminal, applescript, directory, unzip, minecraft

I'm trying to make a AppleScript that downloads a file to the download folder using the variable

```
set downboadFolder to (path to downloads folder) & "Technic-Launcher-OSX.zip" as text
set downloadFolder to downboadFolder as alias
#I downloaded Technic-Launcher-OSX.zip earlier in the code and that works
```

Then I use this code

```
tell application "Finder"
    try
        move downloadFolder to targetFolder
    end try
end tell
```

to move the file to the targetfolder which is

```
try
  set targetFolder to (choose folder)
end try
```

I finish the code with this.

```
set targetFoldera to targetFolder & "Technic-Launcher-OSX.zip" as text
set targetFolderb to targetFoldera as alias
do shell script "/usr/bin/unzip -d /" & (targetFolder) & " " & targetFolderb
```

This is supposed to set foldera to /thefoldertheychoose/TechnicLaunchesOSX.zip
then set folderb to foldera as alias
then unzip the file to their chosen folder
When I run it, I get this

```
unzip:  cannot find or open HD:Users:username:Documents:,     HD:Users:myusername:Documents:.zip or HD:Users:usnername:Documents:.ZIP." number 9
#I chose Documents as the folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
set downboadFolder to (path to downloads folder as text) & "Technic-Launcher-OSX.zip"
set targetFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder" to set targetFile to move downboadFolder to targetFolder
set {targetFile, targetFolder} to {(targetFile as alias)'s POSIX path, targetFolder's POSIX path}
do shell script "cd " & quoted form of targetFolder & " ; /usr/bin/unzip " & quoted form of targetFile
```